# Is there a way to using Spring Security without Web(Spring boot, spring mvc)?

Tags: java, spring-security

So, I want to use Spring Security for authorization in my application, I have users, groups and privileges for all. But, my application using just sockets, without web. So, I don't need to use Spring Boot or Spring MVC.
Can I use Spring Security without it? How should I do it ?

Comment: Spring security core has no dependency on spring web. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/6.0.2/spring-security-core-6.0.2.pom

Comment: But I thought that core is only beans, without web stuff

Comment: Spring core != Spring security core

Answer (score 0):

It does not support out of the box but in theory it should work. But I would imagine you need some non trivial customization which is mainly about configuring `AuthorizationManager` and the related AOP advisors to scan all beans' methods that are annotated with `@PreAuthorize` and etc. in order to create a AOP proxy around them.

Another important point need to consider is how can you identify who is the current user that is using the application for each request ? Do they still need some way to login ? As in the end, you also need some way to integrate with spring security to tell it who is the current user in order to do authorization.

I would suggest you include `spring-mvc`, create an internal dummy URL endpoint such that you can leverage spring security to setup the `AuthorizationManager` and those AOP proxies for you. What remaining is to integrate the logic about how to identify an user when processing each request with spring security which essentially boil down to configuring the `SecurityContext` to hold the current user information. Something like:

```java
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
context.setAuthentication(currentUser);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
```